# Calculated Filed

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, modern-experience, date-time

I have created a calculated filed to convert a date field to another format, the issue I have is the calculated filed populate data for empty fields as well. Is there anyway it can only populate data for the filed which has a data.
As you can see in the attachment, when there is empty cell it just fill it with 30/12/1899.

[image]

Kind Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
=IF(ISBLANK([date]), "", [date])
```

Test result:

[image]

Comment: thanks, so i need to add this as new Calculate field?

Comment: You can try to combine this with your original calculated formula, because you did not give the original calculated formula, I can only give this suggestion.

Comment: =TEXT(testdate,"dd,mm,yyyy")

Comment: =IF(ISBLANK([testdate]), "", TEXT(testdate,"dd,mm,yyyy"))

Comment: Thanks Amos, it works :)

Comment: You could mark my reply as answer and vote it.Thank you.

Comment: you need to help me do this? i cant see any options to say answered ?

Comment: Refer to this:https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Date Column]), "", TEXT([Date Column], "dd/mm/yyyy"))
```

**Microsoft documentation**: [Calculated Field Formulas - Text Formats](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v=office.14)#text-formulas)

**Note**:

1. Put this formula in your calculated column (`Review`)
2. Return your calculated field as **Single line of text**.
3. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (I am not sure but it is based on something language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).